# which statistical parameters are more useful to detect anomalies and outlier? mean max min var?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, statistics, anomaly-detection, anomaly

[image]This time series contains some time frame which each of them are 8K (frequencies)*151 (time samples) in 0.5 sec [overall 1.2288 millions samples per half a second)

I need to find anomalous based on different rows (frequencies) Report the rows (frequencies) which are anomalous? (an unsupervised learning method)
Do you have an idea to which statistical parameter is more useful for it? mean max min median var or any parameters of these 151 sampling?
Which parameter I should use? (I show one sample (151 sample per frequency) from 8k data)

Comment: The answer is data dependent and you have not shown any data.

Comment: What kind of data is this? Based on your description it sounds like Time-Frequency data (spectrogram), like the results of a STFT or simiar? Is it audio or some other domain?

Comment: Yes, it is FFT, time frequency, also I add one of 8k sampling frequency. (151 samples per each frequency)

Comment: If this is indeed time-frequency data, then you should plot it as a spectrogram

Comment: In the plot that you have shown, what does the X and Y axis represent?

Answer (score 0):

Statistical control processes and CUSUM in particular can be useful in identifying outlying values or changes in time series data.

Comment: I used cusum. What about statistical control process you mean?